# how to add /r/n at the time of file reading in php

Tags: php, newline

I have a log file which gives correct formatting in Linux OS, but in windows it looses formatting. New line characters can't get read. I can only make changes at the time of reading/downloading file. Please suggest solution

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['download'])) {
    $file = $dir . "/" . basename($_REQUEST['download']);
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        ob_start();
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `\r\n` isn't `/r/n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of editing the log file I would suggest getting a different editor to look at the file. Most editors (sublime, atom, notepad++, vscode) handle linux style line endings in Windows perfectly fine.

If that is not possible, simply use a regex to replace the line endings:

Replace

```
readfile($file);
```

with

```
$str = file_get_contents($file);
$str = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n/', "\r\n", $str);
echo $str;
```

Takes a bit more memory, since it needs to store the file content in the memory.

Comment: thanks for the comment but its other team who uses Notepad and we can't force them to change general practice.

Comment: @NGupta If this solved your problem I'd appreciate if you accept this answer ;)

Comment: thanks for the solution it worked for .log files but breaking for .gz

Comment: ya I added check based on the extension and then processed.